# .NET 4.5 / Assemblies loading from remote resource without loadFromRemoteSources=true

Tags: configuration, .net-4.5, sandbox

After installing .NET 4.5 beta, I noticed that my calls to Assembly.LoadFrom with a network path succeed without explicitly specifying "loadFromRemoteSources=true" in the application configuration file (whereas with .NET 4.0 this used to result in "System.NotSupportedException: An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions of the .NET Framework.")

I wonder if this, if it indeed is new behaviour and not something special in my setups (I've not yet decompiled the respective reflection classes or debugged the loading process to examine the differences), is an intentional change in policy and will remain in the RTM version?

Answer (score 1):

The docs don't seem to indicate this change in behaviour. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409252(v=vs.110).aspx. And I would have expected a notice of it.

If it does work this way, then you're granting full trust by default and invisibly to a potentially dangerous assemblies and I can't imagine that would be the order of the day.

Have you got it added to machine.config per chance?

Also I would create a small program and target it to the 4.0 platform and induce this exception. Then I would retarget it to 4.5 and see if indeed it's true. Then I'd move the binaries to another machine and test there.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. The first thing I did was grep "%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" for loadFromRemoteSources, which gave no hits (other than binaries).

Comment: My apps in question have been flagged to compile into x86 instruction set. But only hits from the x64 side are from binaries also.

Comment: And to comment the edit: I tested the app on a few dev machines right away. After installing .NET 4.5 my calls to Assembly.LoadFrom started succeeding right away. And just to check that I am not dreaming, I just tested it on one more machine: NotSupportedExeceptions to the point I installed 4.5. After that the calls succeed (on the same network path).

Comment: Wow. Possible worth a log on the Connect?